# What am I doing wrong with this JSON parsing? (iOS)

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I want to make an application which communicates with an API, but I couldn't find out what's wrong with my parsing.

Here is the code:

```
 NSJSONSerialization *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

NSLog(@" jsonObject: %@", jsonObject);

NSURL *img1 = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[jsonObject obj]];
NSURL *img2 = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[jsonObject valueForKey:@"img2"]];
NSURL *img3 = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[jsonObject valueForKey:@"img3"]];
NSData *data1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:img1];
NSData *data2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:img2];
NSData *data3 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:img3];
UIImage *image1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data1];
UIImage *image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data2];
UIImage *image3 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data3];
```

And here is the tree:

```
jsonObject: (
    {
    img1 = "http://www.kozpontiszalon.hu/images/ads/kupon_aug_3.png";
    img2 = "anotherlink";
    img3 = "anotherlink";
    }
)
```

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line should be:

```
NSArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

since your JSON data is an array.

This array has a single dictionary with your image URLs.

```
NSDictionary *urls = jsonObject[0];
NSURL *img1 = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urls[@"img1"]];
```